# How to change Time Format in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, time, format

Hello guys i have a DataFrame like the following

```
   val someDF =
      Seq((1, "034752"), (2, "192354"), (3, "033917")).toDF("id", "transaction_time")
```

I'm trying to convert the values 
like **034752** to **03:47:52** **(HH:mm:ss)**

is there any function that could help me achieve this in spark scala?

tried using

```
date_format(column, "HH:mm:ss")
```

but is not working.
Thanks!

Comment: What is "03:47:52" expected to be ? a String ?

Comment: yes :) it is expected to be a String

Comment: Then I'd go with an UDF, sliding on chars (2 by 2) and applying a mkString(":") on my array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to convert the string to Timestamp first then convert back string in a given format.

```scala
 val someDF = Seq((1, "034752"), (2, "192354"), (3, "033917")).toDF("id", "transaction_time")

 someDF.select(date_format(to_timestamp($"transaction_time", "HHmmss"), "HH:mm:ss")).show(false)

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|date_format(to_timestamp(`transaction_time`, 'HHmmss'), HH:mm:ss)|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|03:47:52                                                         |
|19:23:54                                                         |
|03:39:17                                                         |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The other option is to use udf to insert colon at every interval position.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val someDF = Seq((1, "034752"), (2, "192354"), (3, "033917")).toDF("id", "transaction_time")

val insert: (String, String, Int) => Option[String] = (input, separator, groupSize) => Option(input).map(_.toSeq.sliding(groupSize, groupSize).mkString(separator))
val insertUdf = udf(insert)

someDF.select(insertUdf($"transaction_time", lit(":"), lit(2))).show(false)

+---------------------------+
|UDF(transaction_time, :, 2)|
+---------------------------+
|03:47:52                   |
|19:23:54                   |
|03:39:17                   |
+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example transformation that can be wrapped in an UDF.

```
val time = "034752"
time.sliding(2,2).mkString(":")
```

output :

```
03:47:52
```

So I guess your udf could be defined as :

```
val parseTime = udf{time: String => time.sliding(2,2).mkString(":")}
```

And then :

```
df.withColumn("transaction_time", parseTime($"transaction_time"))
```